# Global Id for appointments

Tags: outlook, exchange-server, outlook-addin

We creating add-in which allows user to save Outlook Appointments to our server.
We want to uniquely identify appointment across all it's attendees so if another user saves the same appointment it wouldn't be saved twice.

Is there a way to get ID which is shared across all attendees?

Answer (score 0):

In the Outlook Object Model, it is [AppointmentItem.GlobalAppointmentID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.appointmentitem.globalappointmentid) property.